# Remix Error - Trying to Follow Ropsten Faucet Instructions

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, ropsten

I have been trying to get testnet Ethereum from Ropsten using Metamask wallet but instead I am getting errors. What am I doing wrong?

Here is what the Ropsten Faucet site said and the error on Remix

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA7p7.jpg

Does anyone know an easier way to connect Ropsten to Metamask?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to intend, but you can go there if you need some ETH on Ropsten https://faucet.metamask.io/

[image]

Double-check on which network you're connected

Comment: I now realize the problem I had. Metamask was connected to Remix so I guess it cannot connect to both Remix and Ropsten at the same time. I tried connecting to Ropsten separately and it worked.